# Block URL if contain specific string

Tags: string, apache, .htaccess

I would like to block URL which contain a specific string. Sample URL:

```
https://example.com/login.php?login=cmd
```

The string is `login=cmd`

I tried this below code in .htaccess, but it doesn't works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} login=cmd
RewriteRule ^login=cmd$ - [F]
RewriteRule .* / [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks for the string in the path **and** the query string. You should look for it in the path **or** the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} login=cmd [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login=cmd
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteRule .* / [R,L]
```

Comment: It doesn't block the mentioned URL. I still can open the webpage.